# Calculate $\sqrt{2i}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I did:

$\sqrt{2i} = x+yi \Leftrightarrow i = \frac{(x+yi)^2}{2} \Leftrightarrow i = \frac{x^2+2xyi+(yi)^2}{2} \Leftrightarrow i = \frac{x^2-y^2+2xyi}{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{x^2-y^2}{2} = 0 \land \frac{2xy}{2} = 1$

$$\begin{cases}
     \frac{x^2-y^2}{2} = 0  \\
     xy = 1\\   \end{cases}   \\
=\begin{cases}
     x^2-y^2 = 0  \\
     x = \frac{1}{y}\\   \end{cases}   \\
=\begin{cases}
     \frac{1}{y}-y^2 = 0  \\
     x = \frac{1}{y}\\   \end{cases}   \\=
\begin{cases}
     \frac{1-y^3}{y} = 0  \\
     -\\   \end{cases}   
\\=
\begin{cases}
     y^3 = 1  \\
     -\\   \end{cases}  
\\=
\begin{cases}
     y = 1  \\
     x =1\\   \end{cases}    $$

And so $\sqrt{2i} = 1+i$, but my book states the solution is $\sqrt{2i} = 1+i$ and $\sqrt{2i} = -1-i$.

What did I forget?

Comment: Do you know polar form of complex numbers?

Comment: From $x^2-y^2=0$ and $x=1/y$ how do you get $1/y-y^2=0$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk More or less so, yes.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Riight, I forgot to square the x.

Comment: @ZacharySelk I think I have a fairly good understanding of the polar form now, could you explain to me how you would solve this problem that way?

Comment: I did that 6 hours ago, lol

Comment: @ZacharySelk Oh I hadn't seen it, sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll stick with your solving algorithm. You obtained (apart from a mistake):
$$\frac{1}{y^2}-y^2 = 0, \implies \frac{1}{y^2} = y^2$$
You can check that both $1$ and $-1$ satisfy this equation! So your chain of systems splits in two: knowing $x = \frac{1}{y}$,
$$y=1 \implies x = 1 \qquad y=-1 \implies x= -1 $$
So you get (as one should expect according to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra) the two solutions
$$\sqrt{2i} = \pm(1+i) $$
Of course, you could have avoided this lengthy procedure in a few ways, for example by taking advantage of the polar form of $2i$. Take a peek at the other answers!

Answer (score 3):

$2i=1+2i+i^2=(1+i)^2$. The roots are $\pm(1+i)$.

Answer (score 2):

In complex numbers, square roots (and cube roots, and fourth roots, etc) are no longer uniquely defined; a square root of a complex number is any value that, when squared, yields the number.

So if one value of $\sqrt{z}$ is $w$, then another value is $-w$, since $w^2 = (-w)^2 = z$.

Comment: To be fair, this ambiguity is present in the real numbers too.  It's just that you can make a clear division between "positive roots" and "negative roots" in that case.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Yes, that's right.  I was going to explain why we do it with the reals and not with complex numbers, but thought that was going too far outside the original question.

Comment: Please, do explain, I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

Write $2i=2e^{i \pi/2+2k\pi}$. Then square root to get: $\sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4+k\pi}$. So your roots are $\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$ and $\sqrt{2}e^{3i\pi/4}$. Which are $\pm(1+i)$.

Comment: Why is $2i=2e^{i \pi/2+2k\pi}$?

Comment: @MarkRead That's the polar form

Comment: Right, just one more thing, why did you do just the root of 2 and not of $e^{i\cdot \theta}$ as well?

Comment: @MarkRead I did do that

Comment: Of course you did, I feel silly now. Alright, I understand now, thanks.